# OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect: Jupyter & Anaconda

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am using Jupyter notebooks via anaconda. When saving a new notebook to a *specific* directory, the whole directory becomes inaccessible, showing this error (image and text below). Other directories and the notebooks inside them are still accessible and able to be run. I am able to save new notebooks and run them in other directories no problem.

Error:

[image]

> Server error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\u1252652.conda\envs\DS011_loss_ratio\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1704, in _execute result = await result File "C:\Users\u1252652.conda\envs\DS011_loss_ratio\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 234, in wrapper yielded = ctx_run(next, result) File "C:\Users\u1252652.conda\envs\DS011_loss_ratio\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\handlers.py", line 116, in get model = yield maybe_future(self.contents_manager.get( File "C:\Users\u1252652.conda\envs\DS011_loss_ratio\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\filemanager.py", line 435, in get model = self._dir_model(path, content=content) File "C:\Users\u1252652.conda\envs\DS011_loss_ratio\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\filemanager.py", line 309, in _dir_model for name in os.listdir(os_dir): OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect: 'C:\Users\u1252652\OneDrive - MMC\Documents\DS011_loss_ratio'

This is strange as i have been working in this directory and saving numerous notebooks to it without error until today. I can delete the notebook that caused it to crash and then it returns to normal and i can run notebooks that were already saved before today.

I am unsure if this is related or not but i also have an issue whereby i have to run `python -m ipykernel install --user` every time i change to a new environment in anaconda, otherwise the executable remains as that of the last environment i ran that command with. Perhaps this is useful i'm not sure, if anyone had advice with this too i'd be grateful.

I have also tried making a new directory, copying over the contents of the dysfunctional directory, and then making a new notebook from there, however this causes the same error.